# How do I close this old German central heating pipe valve?

Tags: valve, water-circulating-heating, old-pipes

I am renovating an old apartment here in Berlin/Germany (built in 1957 I believe) that is connected to the central heating of the entire building. It has an old valve at the pipe that is connected to the main pipe (in the wall) that continues to the apartments above.

I want to close the valve so that the apartment is cut off from the central heating and so that I can replace all old heating pipes and radiators in the apartment.

My guess is that I need to close the small screw in the middle, but it will only screw loose until it comes out. I can't seem to screw it further in to close. The screw seems very weak and I don't want to force it too much.
Also the whole part around the center screw can be removed (see images).

Do I need to heat the pipes to loosen something?
Or will I need to freeze the pipe to cut off the valve and install a new one?

What else can I try?

[image: Heizungsventil1]
[image: Heizungsventil2]
[image: Heizungsventil3]

Comment: From the first picture you are probably missing the handle.  The last picture does not seem to be leaking/ water flowing out, so maybe there is another shut off valve before this that is off.  If any building maintenance people for the building they might help.

Comment: Even if you could get this to "work", I wouldn't trust it to keep working, or to be able to be reopened once you are done. Better to just cut it out and install a proper shutoff now.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.
The pipe is warm so the heating water is flowing through it.  The problem is, to replace it, I would either need to freeze it, or drain the water from the whole central system of the apartments above I believe. I don't know of any other way.

Comment: do you have the key to use on. the the valve. My problem was they do not stay on the valve, so I kept loosing them

Comment: What part did you remove on the last picture ? to check if there is pressure in the system, open one of the vent valve on the radiator

Comment: I believe there is pressure in the system because the radiators get war, which is also why I want to close this valve.  In the last picture I removed the square screw thing. That also, like the screw in the middle, can only be turned to be removed, but couldn't be turned in the direction to be closed further (probably stuck/rusted after decades?)

Comment: Do you know if it is steam or warm water going through the pipe? Also, is there a return pipe going back to the boiler/pump? You might try talking with a local plumber or plumbing supply store to see if they can point you to information on how the system is setup.

Comment: Your last photo seems to show an opening into the inside of that pipe, which suggests to me that there is not continuous steam/water running through it. Could there be another pipe supplying the radiators, and this pipe might be unused or just a drain to return water from condensed steam above? I wonder if the thing you removed was just a plug to allow drainage and not a valve.